# Embed youtube livestream on specific channel

Tags: youtube, stream, embed, live-streaming

Is there a option to embed a youtube livestream only when someone its live?

If someone is offline it shows only name of channel?

I can't find the answer to my question.

Comment: Does it have to be YouTube?  I wrote some code for doing this with Facebook the other day...

Comment: Yes i need it for yt, hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's posible. You can embed an iframe, for example:

```
<iframe id="player"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCJC7T__QoftT5B3QkLUv7pQ"
        width="640"
        height="360"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

You have to provide the channel ID in the channel parameter. In this case is UCJC7T__QoftT5B3QkLUv7pQ